# Using checkbox to copy data form worksheet A to worksheet B

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, data-validation

I am trying to use the new Checkbox function in Google Sheets. I can't figure out how If I click the checkbox in A9 on Worksheet 2 I want the Text in A10 and the $ amount in A11 to be copied to cells B10 and B11 Worksheet A. I am currently using this formula to copy the data from worksheet B to Worksheet A.

```
='Estimate Worksheet'!B9
```

So I am trying to copy the data only if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: It works great, but I am getting an "Invalid: Input must equal Estimate Worksheet B2" message. Could it be because I am pulling data from Sheet B (Worksheet) can copying it to Sheet A (Customer) Also now that I have it working I realized that I have 15 rows of data to use on Sheet B  that could be filled but I only want the rows checked transferred to Sheet A. I would like the rows on Sheet A to be in sequence rather than the randomly checked boxes. Would it help if I share my form with you?

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(Sheet10!A1=TRUE, {Sheet10!B1:C1}, )
```

[image]